# how to resize automatically frames, tkinter widgets using grid when window resizes?

Tags: tkinter, grid, python-3.7, autoresize

I want to create a GUI composed of a main Frame, which contains several Frame and each one contains one or more tkinter widgets (Label, Button, Entry, ...). each of the widgets is positioned with GRID. I also want that when I change the dimensions of my window by pressing the windows buttons at the top right of the window or by using the mouse, that all widgets and text resize.
Is it possible?
Thank you

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use the `grid()` method though the widget sizes are automatically done. You would have to change the font sizes on your widgets. In order for your fonts to resize based on your window you may have to get a bit tricky. You can use simple if statements in an event such as below to get your different sizes.

```py
window = Tk()

def on_resize(self,event):
    w_height = window.winfo_height()
    w_width = window.winfo_width()
    if(w_height > 500 and w_width > 600):
        a_label.configure(font=("Helvetica", "16")
    else:
        a_label.configure(font=("Helvetica", "14")

window.bind(<Configure>, on_resize)
```

You can also create a scale based on what you originally program the window at.

```py
programmed_height = 1080
programmed_width = 1920
programmed_font = 16

window = Tk()

def on_resize(self,event):
    w_height = window.winfo_height()
    w_width = window.winfo_width()
    if(w_width/w_height > programmed_width/programmed_height):  # compare ratio
        scaler = w_height / programmed_height
    else:
        scaler = w_width / programmed_width
    font_size = programmed_font * scaler
    font_tuple = ("Helvetica", str(int(font_size)))  # int() should truncate any decimal points. You could also use round() if you prefer

window.bind(<Configure>, on_resize)
```

This code is meant to be abstract so things are not necessarily correct `a_label` is not declared for example. I'm also not sure the ratio comparison would be sufficient for your needs. As it may change the scaler too soon (< 1 might be better as it would show a transition from landscape to portrait).

Let me know if you have any issues maybe I can help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try